# Alternative to using the LM272 for driving a DC motor

Tags: operational-amplifier

In [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Braitenberg-vehicles-1-4-vehicles-that-3mot3/) instructable, the LM 272 is being used for driving a simple dc motor. My friends and I are trying to use the same concept for our project(which is similar in nature), however there are only general purpose 741s available to us. Ordering the LM 272 is unfortunately not an option since it would get delivered way past our deadline. There is a local electronics shop(unfortunately it doesn't feature an online store) which sells op-amps, and I would like to have a general list of op amps which are capable of driving a motor, before going to the store, so I can be specific about what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Op-Amps cannot provide enough output current to drive DC motors, especially when loaded. If you need a solution quickly, check online for H-bridges and check if your supplier has any of those.

If that fails you can drive the motors with transistors. Your electronic store should at least stock does. [This](http://embedded-lab.com/blog/lab-10-dc-motor-interfacing-to-picmicro/) is one example of how you can do it. If you need bi-directional control you will have to look into building an H bridge.

Comment: We did make one design using where we send pwm signals to the H bridge, however the solution with the op-amp(as shown in the link) is easier to pull off.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to have a general list of op amps which are capable of
>   driving a motor

Short and reasonably accurate answer is NONE. Op-amps can usually deliver about 20 mA before they hit limitations and most of them can't get anywhere close (two streets away) from the performance of a motor driver.

Try looking for solutions that involve transistors and op-amps but even then you are looking at a poorly efficient solution.

Sidenote - presumably you refer to the L272?

Comment: This one : http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/02/9c/bc/75/59/9c/47/bd/CD00000054.pdf/files/CD00000054.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000054.pdf

Comment: A simple YES would have saved me the time of downloading the data sheet.